# WP Post ID Auto Increment

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I was trying something and edited one of the post IDs from 100 to 10000. I switched it back to 100 after the test. Now, every time I add posts, pages, images, etc, the ID would now auto increment starting at 10000, and not at 100. I've already deleted all IDs that above 100, and it still auto increments at 10000++. Can I fix this and have it auto increment starting at 100?

Comment: Why don't you specify `id` explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard MySQL auto incrementing column. If you have access to PHPmyadmin then follow the instructions in this answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885926

Or run this sql...

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT=100
```

Replacing the last number with where you want to start.

Hope that helps

Dan