# How to reset automatically auto_increment keys to 1 when exporting?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made an `export` via `phpmyadmin` the structure of a database ( no data ). Then I created another database and imported in it the previous exported database. When the `import` was finished then I looked the structure of each table of the new database : I saw that all the tables which has an `auto_increment` primary key have their auto_increment options not 1 ! So how to make the `auto_increment` of all tables having an `auto_increment` key to be 1 when doing an `export` ?

Comment: Does this not anwser your query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019698/reset-id-autoincrement-phpmyadmin

Comment: Wich version of phpmyadmin do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

When you export the table there is an option in PHPMyAdmin to reset the AI,but you can do it just by adding `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` to the table definition.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tablename` (
  ...columns...
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

For an empty table, say at the destination point of this export, another way to reset the auto_increment attribute is to run

```
TRUNCATE TABLE mydb.tablename;
```

You can easily do this for all tables dynamically on your new *EMPTY* SQL database.

Read more here: http://trebleclick.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/mysql-set-auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin.html

---

**GOT IT!**

This is a two step solution, using `PHPMyAdmin` you goto Table --> Operations and then on the **Copy Table** panel you copy the table structure without data and uncheck the checkbox `Add AUTO_INCREMENT value` .

Then you goto your new copied table and export that table.

Comment: there are hundreds of table in my database so its very hard work to write this code for every table !

Comment: Export the table structure, then in the SQL file do a find and replace and add the code, you can easily create a script to insert the text at the end of the correct line

Comment: if you export all tables into one SQL file then just find and replace to insert the AI criteria. @pheromix

Comment: it is not only tables that I want to export but also views , triggers and functions !

Comment: no ! at the time it is done table by table then it is not a good practice !